# Get XPath of Substring in an XML Document

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I need to find the exact XPath of a text element in an XML Document. I figured that one way of doing this is by converting the Document to string, adding a temporary tag around the substring, converting it back to Document and then finding the XPath.

This is what I have so far:

```
public String findXPathInXMLString(int startIndex, int endIndex, String string) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    Conversion conversion = new Conversion();
    String xpath;

    //Step 1. Replace start to end index with temporary tag in string document
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(string);
    stringBuilder.replace(startIndex, endIndex, "<findXPathInXMLStringTemporaryTag>" + string.substring(startIndex, endIndex) + "</findXPathInXMLStringTemporaryTag>");

    //Step 2. Convert string document to DOM document & Find XPath of temporary tag in DOM document
    xpath = "/" + getXPath(conversion.stringToDocument(stringBuilder.toString()), "findXPathInXMLStringTemporaryTag");

    //Step 3. Cut off last part of the XPath
    //xpath = xpath.substring(0, 2).replace("/documentXPathTemporaryTag", "");

    //Step 4. Return the XPath
    return xpath;
}

public String getXPath(Document root, String elementName) {
    try {
        XPathExpression expr = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//" + elementName);
        Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(root, XPathConstants.NODE);

        if (node != null) {
            return getXPath(node);
        }
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
    }

    return null;
}

public String getXPath(Node node) {
    if (node == null || node.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        return "";
    }
    return getXPath(node.getParentNode()) + "/" + node.getNodeName();
}
```

The problem that I'm having so far is that the method `getXPath` doesn't put the `[x]` so the XPath that gets returned is wrong because the substring might be in the `[3]`rd instance of a particular tag in which case the XPath will apply to all of the nodes with the same path.  I want to get an exact path that could only refer to one specific element.

Comment: This will not work.  If you temporarily insert part of the XML inside a new node and then get the XPath, the indexes (`[x]`) can wind up different from what they would be otherwise.  Perhaps you should explain to us **what** your ultimate objective is and why you are doing this, and someone can tell you how to do it.

Comment: Ok, suppose you have this XML `<root><child><gc /><gc /></child></root>` and you want the path of the second `gc`, so you put a temporary node around it and get `<root><child><gc /><temp><gc /></temp></child></root>`.  Now you get the path of `temp`, which is `/root/child/temp`.  You remove the `/temp` from this path to get `/root/child`.  This has not obtained the path of the second `gc`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're refusing to explain why you want to do this?

Comment: Surely you mean a perfect balance between defined and undefined, right?

Comment: I can't help until you clearly define and explain what you are trying to do. Nobody can help until you do that.

Comment: Please first explain why you want these XPath values and what they are for.

Comment: Ok, and how do you intend to identify the portion of the XML for which you want to obtain the XPath? How is that specified? I see you have `startIndex` and `endIndex` up there, but how are they determined?

Comment: Is `foo` an element name, or a text value?  That is, is it `<foo />` or `<something>foo is great!</something>`?

Comment: So what if instead of a start and end index, you passed in the value to find.  Would that be a feasible option?  What happens if the sought value occurs more than once?

Comment: What if the method returned an array of the matched XPaths instead of just one XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, how's this (with [ideone example](http://ideone.com/fW1LFX#)):

I changed `startIndex` and `endIndex` to just `index`.  The temporary node can be appended at a single point in the text.

```
public static String findXPathInXMLString(int index, String string) throws XPathExpressionException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
    String xpath;

    //Step 1. Insert temporary tag in insert location
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(string);
    stringBuilder.insert(index, "<findXPathInXMLStringTemporaryTag />");

    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes())
      );

    //Step 2. Convert string document to DOM document & Find XPath of temporary tag in DOM document
    xpath = getXPath(document, "findXPathInXMLStringTemporaryTag");

    //Step 3. Cut off last part of the XPath
    xpath = xpath.replace("/findXPathInXMLStringTemporaryTag", "");

    //Step 4. Return the XPath
    return xpath;
}

private static String getXPath(Document root, String elementName) throws XPathExpressionException 
{
  XPathExpression expr = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//"+elementName);
  Node node = (Node)expr.evaluate(root, XPathConstants.NODE);


  if(node != null) {
      return getXPath(node);
  }

  return null;
}

private static String getXPath(Node node) throws XPathExpressionException {
    if(node == null || node.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        return "";
    }

    return getXPath(node.getParentNode()) + "/" + node.getNodeName() + getIndex(node);
}

private static String getIndex(Node node) throws XPathExpressionException {
    XPathExpression expr = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = '" + node.getNodeName() + "'])");
    int result = (int)(double)(Double)expr.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NUMBER);

    if(result == 0){
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return "[" + (result + 1) + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, very good. Thank you very much. It has worked with every test I've done on it so far.